# Creating a new object inside its parent controller (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

So, for my Rails project I have two models called ButtonOrderDiv and ButtonFinishDiv. They have a has_many/belongs_to relationship where a button_order_div has many button_finish_divs and each button_finish_div belongs to a button_order_div. I am trying to write code so that when the user creates a new button_order_div, the right number of button_finish_divs are automatically created. There is a field for button_order_divs called number_of_parts, which is the number of button_finish_divs to be created. Right now, this is the code that I have inside the ButtonOrderDiv controller:

```
def create
  @button_order_div = ButtonOrderDiv.new(button_order_div_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @button_order_div.save

      number = @button_order_div.number_of_parts

      for i in number
        ButtonFinishDiv.create(button_order_div_id: @button_order_div.id, part: i)
      end

      format.html { redirect_to @button_order_div, notice: 'Item criado com sucesso.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @button_order_div }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @button_order_div.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, inside the if @button_order_div.save condition, I am trying to create a new ButtonFinishDiv, but it is giving me the "undefined method `each' for 3:Fixnum" error. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers (`Fixnum`) don't have the method `each` (when you do a `for x in y`, you are trying to iterate through a number), which is specific to the `array` data structute. What you want is something like this:

```
1.upto(number) do |i|
  ButtonFinishDiv.create(button_order_div_id: @button_order_div.id, part: i)
end
```